# How do I align elements of a div in a "block" horizontally and vertically?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, alignment, vertical-alignment

I have **3 elements** in a div, I want them to **be in a block (vertical) and be aligned horizontally and vertically**. Here is how it looks right now:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<div className="parent">
        <p className="heading">TITLE</p>
        <p className="description"><strong>DISCLAIMER</strong>: The site contains offensive, vulgar langauge which may not be<br/>suitable for many, so enter with caution and do not reveal any personal details</p>
        <Link to="/school"><button className="enterButton">enter the website</button></Link>
    </div>

----------------------
stylesheet.css
----------------------
.parent {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }

  .heading {
    font-size: 76px;
    text-align: center;
  }

  .description {
    font-size: 18px;
    opacity: .7;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 26px;
  }

  .enterButton {
      width: 360px;
      height: 100px;
      background-color: #E1E8ED;
      color: #15202B;
      font-size: 32px;
      font-weight: bolder;
      text-align: center;
      border: none
  }
```

I want them align and below each other like:

```
TITLE
Disclaimer
Enter the website
```

Comment: `.parent` needs, `flex-direction: column;`

Comment: @dalelandry I can't describe the happiness right now mate, spent 2 sleepless nights on this trivial problem! THANKS A LOT!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flex-direction column to set up the alignment of your elements within the flex parent element. You already have the center alignment both axis with `align-items: center` and `justify-content: center`.

```
.parent {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }
```

Will do the trick...

Comment: yep, this works

Comment: hey, if I add `flex-direction: column` the code works fine but I have other pages in my website which are affected by it. For example one of the pages is a `display: grid`, spread out horizontally but suddenly they are vertical and below each other. Is there something I can do?

Comment: So sounds like you have multiple pages that use that same `.parent` class and changing that specific selector causes issues with other pages. Create a unique class for the `.parent` element that has the flex code you want for that page and add it to that element and your CSS page.

Comment: works! thanks a lot!